# Sort a vector and count the identical occurrences

Tags: matlab, sorting, unique

What is a Matlab-efficient way (no loop) to do the following operation: transform an input vector *input* into an output vector *output* such as *output*(i) is the number of integers in input that are less or equal than *input*(i).

For example:

```
input = [5 3 3 2 4 4 4]
```

would give:

```
output = [7 3 3 1 6 6 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use [`input`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) for a variable name, it's a reserved keyword. I'll use `X` here instead.

An alternative way to obtain your desired result would be:

```
[U, V] = meshgrid(1:numel(X), 1:numel(X));
Y = sum(X(U) >= X(V))
```

and here's a one-liner:

```
Y = sum(bsxfun(@ge, X, X'))
```

**EDIT:**
If `X` has multiple rows and you want to apply this operation on each row, this is a little bit trickier. Here's what you can do:

```
[U, V] = meshgrid(1:numel(X), 1:size(X, 2));
V = V + size(X, 2) * idivide(U - 1, size(X, 2));
Xt = X';
Y = reshape(sum(Xt(U) >= Xt(V))', size(Xt))'
```

Example:

```
X =  
   5   3   3   2   4   4   4
   3   9   7   7   1   2   2

Y = 
   7   3   3   1   6   6   6
   4   7   6   6   1   3   3
```

Comment: Thank you. What if X is a matrix with several rows and you want to apply the operation to each row (without any loop)?
ex: X = [5 3 3 2 4 4 4 ; 5 3 3 2 4 4 4] with two rows

Comment: @AdeB I have revised my answer so that this operation can be applied on matrices with multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible answer:

```
output = arrayfun(@(x) sum(x>=input),input)
```

but it doesn't take advantage of vectorization.